# Adding array to existing array without invoking a new key

Tags: php, arrays

I'm building a 3 page submission form, and I'd quite like all of the $_POST results to be stored in a single session variable.

So page 1 starts by setting up the array and adding the first lot of post data:

```
$_SESSION['results'] = array();
$_SESSION['results'] = $_POST // first lot of post data
```

This works great and returns an array like:

```
Array
(
  [name] => bob
  [address] => 1 foobar way
  [age] => 100
)
```

So when I get the resuts from page 2, I want to simply append them to the existing array without invoking a new array+key

```
array_push($_SESSION['results'], $_POST); //second lot of post data
```

To get something like this:

```
Array
(
  [name] => bob
  [address] => 1 foobar way
  [age] => 100
  [job] => rubbish php dev
  [salary] => 1000
)
```

But instead I get:

```
Array
(
  [name] => bob
  [address] => 1 foobar way
  [age] => 100
  [0] => Array
    (
      [job] => rubbish php dev
      [salary] => 1000
    )
)
```

Even more annoying is that I'm sure I had this working properly before I tweaked the code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are searching for array_merge

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also use the [`+` operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php):

```
$combined = $_SESSION['results'] + $_POST;
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Any idea if that has less overhead than using the array_merge function?

Comment: @user2189903 I would certainly guess so, but you would have to benchmark to be sure.

Answer (score 4):

[array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) is the function you're after.

Comment: What a fraggle rock I am! I had array_merge but changed it to array_push. Thanks for the quick responses guys.

Answer (score 1):

`array_merge()` is your answer see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `array_merge()`, look at this: [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)